# Unable to find domain of function

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Given $$f(x) = \dfrac{\tan\pi\left[x\right]}{1+\sin\pi\left[x\right]+\left[x^2\right]}$$

I have no idea how to start with,first I came up with that denominator$\neq 0$ and I got $\sin\pi\left[x\right]+\left[x^2\right]\neq-1$ but I still not getting domain of $x$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does $[x]$ mean integer part of $x$?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen it didn't mentioned in question,but I believe it is integral  part of $x$

Comment: Okay, gotcha, seems like kind of a weird problem then, but if so, I agree with Eugen's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sin\pi\left[x\right]=0 \ \forall x$, so is $\tan\pi\left[x\right]$ because $\sin k\pi=0, \forall k \in \mathbb{Z}$. The only thing you should take care of is $1 + [x^2] \ne 0$ which is true for all $x$, so the domain is $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: So $f(x)=0$ (because numerator is $0$ for any $x$ value) every time and so domain Is $\mathbb{R}$ ?